# Add str no_std Rust

Tags: string, rust, rust-no-std

I've been starting to write no_std Rust code and right now I'm trying to add strings.

This is my code:

```rust
#![no_std]

extern crate libc;

fn add_string(string: &str) {
    const STRING1: &'static str = string;
    const STRING2: &'static str = "String2";
    const TEXT: &str = STRING1 + STRING2;
    unsafe { libc::printf(TEXT.as_ptr() as *const _); }
}

#[no_mangle]
extern "C" fn main() -> ! {
    add_string("String1 ");
}
```

Are there any good libraries for doing something like this in a no_std program?

Comment: Are you aware of  no-std-compat? 
https://crates.io/crates/no-std-compat    
     
"A #![no_std] compatibility layer that will make porting your crate to no_std easy."

Comment: Thank you @intltechventures this seems like it could help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

##### [Read the Docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/)

###### The answer is always there

My Solution:

```rs
#![no_std]

extern crate alloc;
use alloc::{format,string::String};

fn add_string(string: &str) {
    let res: String = format!("{} String2", string);
    unsafe { libc::printf(res.as_ptr() as *const _); }
}

#[no_mangle]
extern "C" fn main() -> ! {
    add_string("String1 ");
}
```

Comment: i get `can't find crate for alloc. can't find crate`, is this expected?